# Test Hosts Available for NMAP Scanning?

Tags: nmap

Are there any known hosts online that make themselves available for port scanning in order to learn tools like NMAP?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://scanme.nmap.org/
```

This host exist solely for the purpose of testing nmap. Here is the wording from the page:

> We set up this machine to help folks learn about Nmap and also to
>   test and make sure that their Nmap installation (or Internet
>   connection) is working properly. You are authorized to scan this
>   machine with Nmap or other port scanners. Try not to hammer on the
>   server too hard. A few scans in a day is fine, but dont scan 100 times
>   a day or use this site to test your ssh brute-force password cracking
>   tool.

Answer (score 0):

While [@Jack's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/210732/163495) is absolutely correct and in the vast majority of cases the preferred way, scanning your own machine or a virtual machine running on your system is a viable option as well, which also gives you some advantages in comparison to an external machine:

- **Higher availability:** If you don't have an internet connection, `localhost` will still be accessible to you. This could be relevant, for instance, on a long ride home from university.
- **Ability to modify the environment:** If you want to try something specific, such as a specific script, service detection, OS detection, etc.
- **Safe from Proxies:** If you are in a network where an overzealous proxy is blocking your port scans, then scanning a local machine is the only option.
- **Higher stability:** While arguably unlikely, it's not certain that nmap will keep `scanme.nmap.org` alive indefinitely.

So in conclusion, don't be afraid to scan your own machines too.